# Task Scheduler Not Running Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I've a task scheduler job that isn't running a batch file for us. The batch file runs if done manually but won't through the scheduler.

I'm getting following error on task scheduler

```
 "task scheduler failed to launch action cmd.exe in instance"
```

I've seen other questions on this issue and recommendations were to add in Start In path (I've done this and it doesn't have "" around the Start In path, it does on the program/script path), and try changing mapped drives to UNC (done this) but still getting same issue.

Would anyone have any ideas why it doesn't work, or anything else I can provide for it?

Thanks

Comment: Is it executing with Admin privileges i.e. `Run as Administrator`?

Comment: If `user account` is not set, tasks will run under system account, and may have not access permissions to whatever resources they may need (i.e `UNC` paths). So, my guess is that you need to set the task to run under some `user account` with enough privileges.

Comment: Ya, it was running with admin privileges, and was running under my own user account. It actually works when I take out the Start In Path for some reason so going to see how long it'll work like that for now

Comment: the above solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

When I take out the Start In path, it works.