# Windows 10 Task Scheduler tasks don't even try to run

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to get a task in windows scheduler to run every 10 mins.

In the following image there are two blue lines, this is only one task but I have screenshot them at different times after refreshing the page.

[image: Task Scheduler issue]

As you can see in the image Task Scheduler, on the bottom blue line under last run time it says 3:37pm and next run time is 5:02pm. then on the top blue line I have a screenshot the same task after 5:02pm, it hasn't updated the last run time but it has pushed the next run time forward 10 mins.

If I right mouse click on the task and manually run it, it works. Its just the timer functionality of task scheduler that isn't working, I'm guessing i have misconfigured it somehow.

These are the options I have set, everything else is on it's default value.

Trigger

- Daily
- Recur every 1 day
- Start today
- Repeat task every 10 mins
- for a duration of indefinitely
- Expire tomorrow
- Enabled

Conditions

- Do not Start task only on AC
- Wake the computer to start the task

Settings

- Run task as soon as possible after scheduled start is missed

What do I need to change to make this actually run every 10 mins?

Evidence of me searching before posting.

- [Task Scheduler Not Running Batch File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45008182/task-scheduler-not-running-batch-file) I don't use a start path.
- [Batch file runs manually but not through Windows 10 Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535935/batch-file-runs-manually-but-not-through-windows-10-task-scheduler) I'm not running over the network but I did elevate privs, even though my program doesn't write any files.
- [Running PowerShell in Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635118/running-powershell-in-task-scheduler) Doesn't mention timer functionality only action functionality.
- [Task Scheduler failed to start. Additional Data: Error Value: 2147943726](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44348330/task-scheduler-failed-to-start-additional-data-error-value-2147943726) I'm not trying to run while I'm logged out and I'm not getting this error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that when I change the 'interval' from 'indefinitely' to '1 day' it works.

Comment: This was my issue as well. A task that recurred every 1 day for a duration of "indefinitely" would never run on schedule, but if I changed it to "1 day" it works. What's strange is that the "indefinitely" setting worked in Windows Server 2012 but not Server 2019 (I noticed this problem when migrating some tasks to a newer VM)

Answer (score 2):

Change **settings** from **Daily** to **One time** and keep duration **Indefinitely**.